# In Ubuntu, how do I figure out my DPI?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, lcd, dpi

What is the simplest way to check my DPI in Ubuntu 9.10?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
xdpyinfo|grep resolution
```

worked better for me. It means you don't have to read through hundreds of lines of text.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `xdpyinfo` command. If you want to narrow down the output:

```
xdpyinfo | grep dots
```

output:

```
john@awesome~:xdpyinfo | grep dots
resolution:    92x92 dots per inch
```