# How can I find out what DPI that my laptop supports?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, lcd, dpi

I have a new HP dv7t laptop. Can I find out what DPI this laptop supports so that I can set my Ubuntu settings? I think I got the resolution working right after I installed the proprietary driver for the Nvdia graphics card.

Thank you.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://superuser.com/questions/69207/in-ubuntu-how-do-i-figure-out-my-dpi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

17.3" diagonal @ 1600 x 900 native resolution = 106.11 dpi

`pixels_per_inch = sqrt(pixels_horizontal^2 + pixels_vertical^2) / inches_diagonal`

Answer (score 0):

It's common for laptops to have different screen options, often with different resolutions.  I'm afraid we can't tell you what your laptop has.

A quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=hp+dv7t+resolution) shows 1680x1080 and 1600x900 as common resolutions for dv7t.

For what setting do you need to know this?

#### About DPI

DPI means "dots per inch" and depends on, but is different from, resolution.  It's somewhat variable, as the computer doesn't actually need to know it to display on screen.  (In other words, you don't actually have to have an accurate DPI setting for most uses.)

I believe you're actually asking for the resolution here, but if you already have the resolution, you can measure the physical screen size to get your actual DPI: e.g. 15" wide – not diagonal – with 1680 horizontal resolution is 112 DPI.

Answer (score 0):

The standard options for DPI are 100 and 75 for non-scaling fonts.  Most monitors now are 100 DPI, and low resolution monitors are 75.  For most screens Ubuntu will query the screen for its resolution and sent it automatically.  You no longer need to set it.